# incomplete shell font on ubuntu VPS

Tags: command-line, fonts

I try to find in internet any solution which can rapair shell font on my Ubuntu VPS server. Instead nice border lines in Midnight Commander i have letter-bushes.

[image]

Can anybody help me fix this terrible "borders"? When i log in into another server all looks fine... the problem appear only when im logged into my VPS with Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this usually related to encoding of your shell. please add the output of `env | egrep "(LANG|LC)"` to your question.

Comment: Im newbie on Unix. You mean execute this in terminal as command?

Comment: exactly ;-) just close mc and copy and paste the whole command to the ssh window.

Comment: Nothing appear. No errors, no results... just new line for next commands ;]

`root@xnineVPS:~# env | egrep "(LANG|LC)"`
`root@xnineVPS:~#`

Comment: are you per chance using putty to connect to the vps?

Comment: Correct! I use PuTTy for connection with shell of my hostings and VPS

Comment: does this solve your problem? http://www.andremiller.net/content/getting-midnight-commander-line-drawing-work-putty

Comment: I find it before... is not! :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49646/discussion-between-phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann-and-x9design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some chatting and some fiddling around with `mc` and `bash` `env`, the reason was that `env LANG` was unset and LC_* env variables set to POSIX while mc was set to use [darkened skin](https://github.com/zpuskas/linux/blob/master/home/.local/share/mc/skins/darkened.ini).

When switching to default skin, the issue was gone for me (using ssh on linux) but persisted for OP using putty on windows.

We solved the issue with another locale:

```
update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8
```

after re-login as root, the problems are gone.